# Fill in NaN values for left join by sampling from right table

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot figure out a nice panda-ish way to fill in missing NaN values for left join by sampling from right table.

e.g 
    joined_left = left.merge(right, how="left", left_on=[attr1], right_on=[attr2])
from left and right

```
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  9  9  9
4  1  3  2

   0  1  2
0  1  2  2
1  1  2  3
2  3  2  2
3  3  2  9
4  3  2  2
```

produces smth like

```
   0  1_x  2_x  1_y  2_y
0  1    1    1  2.0  2.0
1  1    1    1  2.0  3.0
2  2    2    2  NaN  NaN
3  3    3    3  2.0  2.0
4  3    3    3  2.0  9.0
5  3    3    3  2.0  2.0
6  9    9    9  NaN  NaN
7  1    3    2  2.0  2.0
8  1    3    2  2.0  3.0
```

How do I sample a row from a right table instead of filling NaNs?

This is what I tried so far [playground](http://tpcg.io/BfYYDG):

```
left = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2],[3,3,3], [9,9,9], [1,3,2]]
right = [[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[3,2,2], [3,2,9], [3,2,2]]
left = np.asarray(left)
right = np.asarray(right)
left = pd.DataFrame(left)
right = pd.DataFrame(right)
joined_left = left.merge(right, how="left", left_on=[0], right_on=[0])

while(joined_left.isnull().values.any()):
    right_sample = right.sample().drop(0, axis=1)
    joined_left.fillna(value=right_sample, limit=1)

print joined_left
```

Basically sample randomly and use fillna() for first occurance of NaN value to fill in...but for some reason I get no output.

Thank you!

One of outputs could be

```
   0  1_x  2_x  1_y  2_y
0  1    1    1  2.0  2.0
1  1    1    1  2.0  3.0
2  2    2    2  2.0  2.0
3  3    3    3  2.0  2.0
4  3    3    3  2.0  9.0
5  3    3    3  2.0  2.0
6  9    9    9  3.0  2.9
7  1    3    2  2.0  2.0
8  1    3    2  2.0  3.0
```

with sampled `3  2  2`and`3  2  9`

Comment: What is your expected output?. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SandeepKadapa provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sample` with `fillna`

```
joined_left = left.merge(right, how="left", left_on=[0], right_on=[0],indicator=True) # adding indicator
joined_left
Out[705]: 
   0  1_x  2_x  1_y  2_y     _merge
0  1    1    1  2.0  2.0       both
1  1    1    1  2.0  3.0       both
2  2    2    2  NaN  NaN  left_only
3  3    3    3  2.0  2.0       both
4  3    3    3  2.0  9.0       both
5  3    3    3  2.0  2.0       both
6  9    9    9  NaN  NaN  left_only
7  1    3    2  2.0  2.0       both
8  1    3    2  2.0  3.0       both
nnull=joined_left['_merge'].eq('left_only').sum() # find all many row miss match , at the mergedf
s=right.sample(nnull)# rasmple from the dataframe after dropna 
s.index=joined_left.index[joined_left['_merge'].eq('left_only')] # reset the index of the subset fill df to the index of null value show up 
joined_left.fillna(s.rename(columns={1:'1_y',2:'2_y'})) 
Out[706]: 
   0  1_x  2_x  1_y  2_y     _merge
0  1    1    1  2.0  2.0       both
1  1    1    1  2.0  3.0       both
2  2    2    2  2.0  2.0  left_only
3  3    3    3  2.0  2.0       both
4  3    3    3  2.0  9.0       both
5  3    3    3  2.0  2.0       both
6  9    9    9  2.0  3.0  left_only
7  1    3    2  2.0  2.0       both
8  1    3    2  2.0  3.0       both
```

Comment: could you pls briefly explain the logic

Comment: @YohanRoth added

Comment: @YohanRoth you should assign it back df=df.fillna(s)

Comment: it's not really sampling from right table, but rather from right table values that we brought in the join

Comment: @YohanRoth got you , let me fix

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate. Btw as a side note, when I run this piece of code on real data I get errors like this
"Length mismatch: Expected axis has 253 elements, new values have 276 elements"
and 
"Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'". Do you know possible reasons for this to happen?" I cannot get why this happens because real data files are huge, but I cannot catch it on toy example.

Comment: This one I am running on old example. 

Length mismatch: Expected axis has 253 elements, new values have 276 elements.    

Join shape  (747, 17)

nnull  253

s.shape  (471, 17)

sp.shape  (253, 17)

setting join index with 
(276,)

Comment: @YohanRoth Maybe you have the Null value in your data frame before merge ?

Comment: that's true. is there a simple way to limit my null considerations only for columns that I bring from a right table so that I dont have mismatch in numbers ?

Comment: @YohanRoth let me fix

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your help